# Differences between select() and table.select()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

What are the differences between `select` and `tablename.select()`? When I pass column name to `table.select` like:

```
table.select(table.c.name)
```

the sql is like

```
select * from tablename where tablename.name
```

and when I pass a column to `select` (instance method):

```
select([table.c.name])
```

the sql is like

```
select name from tablename
```

I want the same result as `select` with `table.select`.

When I read the docs of `select` it's the same so it's the same method but why they have a different behavior?

Comment: According to the documentation, table.select receives a WhereClause (default = None) and an array of strings. Since you passed only one string, it may have received it as the WhereClause.
Try doing this: table.select([table.c.name])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Presumably, with `select()` you mean [`sqlalchemy.sql.select()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select).

The `select()` function expressly takes a set of columns as it's argument, and it's result is a stand-alone [`Select` instance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select). You can also pass in a `FromClause` object (like a table or an alias) and it'll take the columns from that object. This is described in detail in the [Selecting chapter](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#selecting) of the core tutorial.

The [`.select()` method on a table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.FromClause.select) on the other hand, takes a `whereclause` first argument, *not* a set of columns. In other words, whatever you pass to *that* method, form the `WHERE` filter for the select, not the columns you wanted to select. By passing in a column for the where clause, you are selecting all columns, but filtering on `WHERE [columnname]`. Not much of a filter, since there the expression doesn't really restrict what rows will match.

Proper use of the `table.select()` function is to pass in a selection filter, and the intention to select all columns:

```
table.select(table.c.name != None)
```

which would be compiled to:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE tablename.name IS NOT NULL;
```

(although SQLAlchemy, knowing what columns exist, expands `*` to an explicit list of all `table` column names).

You should stick to the `select()` function to select only specific columns.

Comment: According to the Selecting chapter of core tutorial, `select([table])` will expand to each of its columns and generates `From` clause.

Comment: @dralshehri: I'll try to check this later, but that's probably a new feature introduced since I wrote this answer (which is now over 7 years old). We are now 5 versions along!

Comment: @dralshehri Note that the point of the question was to pick a subset of columns, not all the columns in the table.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for your answer which was helpful even after several years